# ffmpeg, stereo + 5.1 surround, and YouTube's "Recommended upload encoding settings"

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, h.264, aac

I'm trying to make sense of something YouTube has listed on their recommended upload encoding settings for the best possible quality. Here's the link: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171#zippy=%2Caudio-codec-aac-lc

Specifically this line:

> - Channels: Stereo or Stereo + 5.1

I'm Googling for "Stereo + 5.1" and anything to do with ffmpeg but I can't seem to find much of anything.

I have trailers with surround audio I need to export for a client for YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a stereo downmix. (5.1 to stereo).

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a5.1stereo

Then you combine your

- video
- audio (stereo) and
- audio (5.1)

into one file with a total of 3 tracks.